# Горячие клавиши в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

В книгах описано как привязать горячие клавиши к методам используя связку (Alt+...), но мне нужно чтобы событие нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре обрабатывалось при нажатии одной единственной клавиши (без нажатия Alt), например нужно чтобы при нажатии на клавиатуре клавиш "+" или "-" в окне программы производилось нажатие соответствующих кнопок в окне программы, а еще лучше - прямой запуск функций `key_plus` и `key_minus`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

def key_plus():
    print('Key "+" pressed')

def key_minus():
    print('Key "-" pressed')

main_window = QWidget()
buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout()
button_one = QPushButton('нажата клавиша "+" на клавиатуре')
button_two = QPushButton('нажата клавиша "-" на клавиатуре')
button_one.clicked.connect(key_plus)
button_two.clicked.connect(key_minus)
buttons_layout.addWidget(button_one)
buttons_layout.addWidget(button_two)
main_window.setLayout(buttons_layout)
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не обязательно связки использовать, можно и просто к одной кнопке:

- `button_one.setShortcut('+')`
- `button_two.setShortcut('-')`

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

def key_plus():
    print('Key "+" pressed')

def key_minus():
    print('Key "-" pressed')

main_window = QWidget()
buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout()
button_one = QPushButton('нажата клавиша "+" на клавиатуре')
button_one.setShortcut('+')
button_two = QPushButton('нажата клавиша "-" на клавиатуре')
button_two.setShortcut('-')
button_one.clicked.connect(key_plus)
button_two.clicked.connect(key_minus)
buttons_layout.addWidget(button_one)
buttons_layout.addWidget(button_two)
main_window.setLayout(buttons_layout)
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: доброго дня. PS. Однако способ указания и интерпретации этих сочетаний клавиш зависит от раскладки клавиатуры.

Comment: А как иначе? :) Для набора без раскладки (т.е. чтобы `+` нажимался над `qwerty` без зажатого Shift) нужно включить на клаве Num Lock и набирать на Num Pad

Comment: @S.Nick А есть вариант который не будет учитывать раскладку клавиатуры?

Comment: @arachnoden  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues